# as3 app location data google maps

Tags: xml, google-maps, actionscript-3, location

It is still possible to run google maps from Flash/as3. I've seen information suggesting that either htmlLoader and or stagewebview etc can bypass the google api which is no longer but can't find any examples to back this up.

I want to be able to load an xml file which lists, places, locations and the details covering the target object if selected so that the choice displays a target and zooms in to the map coordinates.

Thanks in advance if anyone could be kind enough help point me in the right direction with this.

Comment: Take a look at this [example using `StageWebView` and a server](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1315886?tstart=0), or you could look into using [Modest Maps](http://modestmaps.com/) for AS3.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code once :
It depends on location :

```
var webView: StageWebView = new StageWebView();


webView.stage = this.stage;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight - 200);


btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, locating)

function locating(e: MouseEvent): void {
var lat:String = //location latitude
var lng:String = //location longitude
    url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + lat + "," + lng;
    webView.loadURL(url);

}
```